# Flutter - DateFormat from String to US date format

Tags: json, flutter, date

I have a container/text thats being brought back from as part of a list view. It builds a dynamic list from the database. The .createAt is the datetime.

```
                                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                            child: Text(
                                                sl<IIndividualDataProvider>()
                                                    .reads[index]
                                                    .createdAt,
                                               ),
                                          ),
                                        )
```

For the life of me I cannot get this into a US date format of mm-dd-yyyy.

Any clues as to what i am missing? I've been playing with DateFormat but dont understand how to wrap the result of

```
sl<IIndividualDataProvider>().reads[index].createdAt,
```

into a different dateformat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateFormat` class from `intl` package
Examples:

```dart
    final date=DateTime.parse('1996-07-10');
    print(DateFormat('yMd').format(date)); //               -> 7/10/1996
    print(DateFormat.yMMMMd('en_US').format(date)); //      -> July 10, 1996
```

[DateFormat class](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)